# Arduino Mega reading same information that it's sending out via serial

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, uart

So I have an Arduino Mega and I'm attempting serial communication with another device, and I ran into this weird issue.

Let's say I use Serial1.write to send out hex A-F. If I read on that same port (Serial1, print out what I read on Serial0), **with NO wires plugged in the serial port**, I get a mirror of what I'm sending out in my read function. I've tested this theory on multiple serial ports, as well as different Megas.

How is this interference happening? Do I have an incorrect understanding of the serial buffers? What can I do to stop it? It's causing interference in communicating with my external device.

Here is a super short program to test this theory.

```cpp
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(115200);  
}

void loop() 
{
  char test[15]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    test[i] = i; 

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
     Serial1.write(test[i]);

  while(Serial1.available() > 0 ) 
   {
    byte c = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(' '); 
    Serial.print(c, HEX); 
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I came back the next day with my O-scope and the yellow line is the TX and the blue line is the RX. I was not getting the crosstalk anymore in the Serial port, but on the scope shows the RX line was only being effected about 250mV in perfect unison to the TX. I tried connecting everything back up the same way but I was not able to replicate the issue. Somehow whatever I had going on when I posted this was causing the RX line to be affected great enough for the Mega to pick up on it over serial. For now I'm just blaming it on escaped aliens from Area 51 :)

[image]

Comment: it is acting as if the local echo is enabled ... there does not appear to be a setting for it though

Comment: does this happen if you swap serial and serial1? What happens if you try them both at 9600?

Comment: you reinvented radio communication :-)

Comment: @esoterik idk, I need serial for seeing my data so I didn't swap. I tried it on Serial2, same issue, then I tried it on Serial3 and it worked better, but not great. I tried different baud rates as well

Comment: Note that a scope typically has 1 MΩ input impedance. This would be increased by a factor 10 if using a 10× probe. Connecting the scope to RX is equivalent to adding an extremely weak pull-down resistor, which is enough to significantly reduce the cross-talk effect.

Comment: I got the same results from my setup; 0-5V on the Tx line, 0-.3V on the Rx line.  As an experiment I connected two parallel 30cm wires to Tx & Rx. This resulted in a higher cross-talk level, but still did not result in any 'echo reads'. I'm pretty sure that in order to get the necessary 0-3V or so on the Rx line to actually get successful data reads would require some sort of wired connection.  I think your escaped aliens may have pulled one over on you ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran a slightly modified version of your test code on a Mega 2560 and got no echo at all;  Unless I totally misunderstood your problem description, there must be something else going on.  Here's the code I ran:

```cpp
char test[15];

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        //Serial.print(i);
        test[i] = i;
        Serial.print(test[i],HEX);
    }
    Serial.println();

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        Serial.print("test["); Serial.print(j); 
        Serial.print("] = ");Serial.println(test[j],HEX);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        Serial1.write(test[i]);
    }

    Serial.println(Serial1.available());

    while (Serial1.available() > 0)
    {
        byte c = Serial1.read();
        Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.print(c, HEX);
    }
}
```

And here's a bit of the output seen on Serial0:

```cpp
Opening port
Port open
VMDPV_1|1_�Se�
0123456789ABCDE
test[0] = 0
test[1] = 1
test[2] = 2
test[3] = 3
test[4] = 4
test[5] = 5
test[6] = 6
test[7] = 7
test[8] = 8
test[9] = 9
test[10] = A
test[11] = B
test[12] = C
test[13] = D
test[14] = E
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

As you can see, the Serial1 read buffer was always empty.

Did I misunderstand something you said?

Comment: I updated my post, see the new info. I ran the same thing again a few days later and I couldn't replicate it, however the perfectly matching RX and TX on the scope leads me to believe that something I had going on made the interference great enough that I could read it back.

Comment: Thank you for helping out